# CSS positioning sprite next and prev button images

Tags: css

I am creating a simple slide show.

I have done everything, but am struggling to position the prev and next buttons ( using sprites )

I have knocked up a demo, and exact concept of how i want it to look.
Any help appreciated,

Demo: http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/slider/

ADDED a FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/k9tZB/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@422,

your sprites are ok. there is a problem of `float` so give float to your a & div.

```
a.pre{
float:left;
}
a.next{
float:right;
}
div #go-prev{
float:left;
}
```

& adjust padding & margin according to them.
check the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/UMDRt/

you are define `classes & id's` that's why i am given float on it & in previous example `.pre & .next` are classes which you are not implemented in your html that's why isn't work.

Comment: added fiddle to main post if that helps @sandeep

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but as you can see from your fiddle it doesnt work. Thanks anyway

Comment: @422; check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/k9tZB/9/ , in your fiddle example you define js sourcre & jquery 1.4.4

Comment: Cheers Sandeep. Yep that did it, I added some margins: http://jsfiddle.net/k9tZB/14/